# Semidirect product of two cyclic groups

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism, semidirect-product

> Describe all semidirect products of $C_n$ by $C_m$ (ie $C_n \rtimes C_m$) where $m,n \in \mathbb{N_+}$

Note: For the first attempt one needs to find all homomorphisms from $C_m \to U(n)$, but the situation differs a lot for different pairs of $n ,m$, is there a better way to find all structures of $C_n \rtimes C_m$?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) provided a general presentation of this product which I do not know how it was worked out.

Comment: $U(n)$ has order $\phi(n)$, so there are nontrivial homomorphisms if and only if $\gcd(m,\phi(n))\gt 1$.

Comment: That's true, but if there are non-trivial homomorphisms then how to get general presentations of the semidirect product?

Comment: The presentation of the semidirect product is $$\langle x,y\mid x^n = y^m=1, x^y = x^{\varphi(y)}\rangle,$$ where $\varphi\colon C_m\to U(n)$ is the chosen homomorphism, and $y$ generates $C_m$.

Comment: The semidirect product is completely determined by how $y$ (the generator of $C_m$) acts on $x$ (the generator of $C_n$). The action is given by conjugation, so you just need to say what $x^y = y^{-1}xy$ is; it must be a power of $x$ (since $\langle x\rangle$ is normal), so it is of the form $y^{-1}xy = x^k$; the order of $x^k$ must be prime to $n$, and $k^m\equiv 1\pmod{\phi(n)}$ must hold. This gives you the multiplication table, so that's a presentation of the group.

Comment: Thanks! It's clear to me now. the phi(y) is in U(n) thus coprime to n which is equal to the symbol "k" in the presentaion given by the wiki site above.

Answer (score 4):

As any automorphism of $C_n$ is of the form $g \mapsto g^k$ for some $k$, such that $GCD(n, k) = 1$, we have any semidirect product $C_n \rtimes C_m$ being of the form $\langle a, b|a^n = e, b^m = e, b^{-1}ab = a^k\rangle$. From that presentation we get, that $a = b^{-m}ab^{m} = a^{k^m}$. Thus, $ord(a) = n$ iff $n|k^m - 1$.

So any such semidirect product is defined by presentation $\langle a, b|a^n = e, b^m = e, b^{-1}ab = a^k\rangle$, where $n|k^m - 1$