# A realization of a group defined by semidirect product

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, semidirect-product

Consider the group $G=C_3\rtimes C_9$, where $\rtimes$ denotes the semidirect product and $C_n$ denotes the cyclic group with $n$ elements.

Can this group elements be describe using matrices with respect to regular matrix multiplication? In not, is there an easy way to understand its elements? Thanks.

Comment: The definition of a semidirect product $H \rtimes K$ requires specification of a homomorphism $K \to {\rm Aut}(H)$, so it makes no sense in general to write "the group $G =H\rtimes K$". But as it happens, there is only one isomorphism class of groups $C_3 \rtimes C_9$, which is the direct product $C_3 \times C_9$, so I wonder whether you meant to write $C_9 \rtimes C_3$?

Comment: By https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151887/semidirect-product-of-two-cyclic-groups?rq=1

Comment: You can represent any finite group using matrices with respect to regular matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only isomorphism class of nontrivial semidirect products $C_9 \rtimes C_3$ (where nontrivial means not isomorphic to the direct product), and such a group is defined by the presentation $\langle x,y | x^9=y^3=1, y^{-1}xy=x^4 \rangle$.

This group can be represented by $3 \times 3$ complex matrices, with
$$x \to \left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&0&1\\w&0&0\\0&1&0\end{array}\right),
\ \ \ \ y \to \left(\begin{array}{ccc}w&0&0\\0&w^2&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right),$$
where $w$ is a primitive cube root of $1$.

Comment: Thank Derek! It was very helpful